# Is there any threshold page load time to get spike in the conversion?

Tags: performance, page-speed, optimization, conversions

I was reading an article [here](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2012/02/28/4-awesome-slides-showing-how-page-speed-correlates-to-business-metrics-at-walmart-com/) where I found very interesting correlation of conversion rate and page load time. I can't get 2 things here:

1. Why graph is almost flat from 5 seconds to 11 seconds page load time and sudden spike when we move from 4 seconds to 1 second? Is <2 second page load is real threshold to solve this issue?
2. Why in data conversion rate has dropped for page load time of 11 seconds to 13 seconds while it goes up for 13 to 15 second? Is it wrong data?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your graph already answers your questions about the conversion rate spike.   I'm not sure what answer you are expecting to be added to that.

Comment: As for the changes at the end of the graph, it is likely due to small sample size.  There are relatively few visitors that fell in those buckets and it just happens that a couple converted and skewed the percentages.   My guess is that if the experiment were repeated, the graph would look similar, but some details like that would change.   With a large enough sample size, it would probably be a smooth curve.

Comment: I just want to check other webmasters opinion here. Just wanted to verify if someone else has similar or contradicting experience. If you have any experience or data like this, please share here.

Comment: Users certainly leave websites that take 3+ seconds to load each page.  My guess would have been that users were a bit less pick under 3 seconds but it has also been a few years since I really looked into it users may be expecting faster sites now.

Comment: I think that these articles will help you: THE PERFORMANCE OF WEB APPLICATIONS: CUSTOMERS ARE WON OR LOST IN ONE SECOND http://www.aberdeen.com/research/5136/ra-performance-web-application/content.aspx  ++  Find out how you stack up to new industry benchmarks for mobile page speed https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/marketing-resources/data-measurement/mobile-page-speed-new-industry-benchmarks/  ++ The need for mobile speed https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com/articles/mobile-speed-matters/

Comment: Could anyone tell me what is 'Population' in this graph. Is it number of pages with given page load time?